# How can i add items from database to checklist box?

Tags: c#, sql, database

I've a database project , and i'm needed to add elements from database to checklist box,, how can i do that??

this is the code i have written but its seems that it has a problem

```
private void CheckedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connection_string = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-MMHA4KL;Initial Catalog=Movie rental;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connection_string);
            string Add_to_checkbox = "SELECT name from [Actor]";
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(Add_to_checkbox, connection);
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader read_name = comm.ExecuteReader();
            int lastindex = 0;
            while(read_name.Read())
            {
                string name = read_name.ToString();
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(name);

            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though there is only one field being selected in your query, you need to specify it in the read. try

```
string name = read_name["name"].ToString();
```

Comment: still the same problem exist , no values are added

Comment: and you have a table in your database called actor that has rows in it?

Comment: yes , i was run this query and it returns what i need in SQL

Comment: The only other thing I could think to tell you is to double-check your connection string and make sure you are accessing the same database.